# Firebase Document will not delete, probably a timing error, swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to load data into a tableview. Once a user clicks on the cell, it should delete. However, nothing happens. I know that it runs, error is nil, I know that the document ID exists, so I'm unsure as to why the document isn't deleting. Here is some code:

Here's where i load in my data:

```
self.comments = []
for index in 0...1
{
    var postCategory = ""
    if index == 0 { postCategory = "cPosts" }
    else { postCategory = "rPosts"}
    
    db.collection(postCategory).order(by: "rankValue", descending: true).getDocuments
    { snapshot, error in
        guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
        
        for postDoc in snapshot!.documents
        {
            self.getUsername(uid: self.uid!)
            { username in
                self.secondGroup.enter()
                self.ref = self.db.collection(postCategory).document(postDoc.documentID).collection("comments")
                self.ref?.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments
                { snapshot, error in
                    guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
                    
                    for doc in snapshot!.documents
                    {
                        let comment = Comment(data: doc.data())
                        comment.docID = doc.documentID
                        
                        self.comments.append(comment)
                        
                        self.firstGroup.enter()
                        self.repRef = self.db.collection(postCategory).document(postDoc.documentID).collection("comments").document(comment.docID).collection("replies")
                        self.repRef?.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments
                        { snapshot, error in
                            guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
                            
                            for doc in snapshot!.documents
                            {
                                let reply = Reply(data: doc.data())
                                reply.docID = doc.documentID

                                self.comments.append(reply)
                            }
                            self.firstGroup.leave()
                        }
                    }
                    self.firstGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                        self.secondGroup.leave()
                    }
                    self.secondGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                        completion(self.ref!, self.repRef!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where I actually delete the document:

```
self.ref?.document(self.comments[indexPath.row].docID).collection("replies").getDocuments
    { snapshot, error in
        guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
        
        for doc in snapshot!.documents
        {
            doc.reference.delete { error in
                guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
            }
        }
    }

    self.ref?.document(self.comments[indexPath.row].docID!).delete { error in
        guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
        print()
    }
    self.repRef?.document(self.comments[indexPath.row].docID).delete { error in
        print("ranhere also")
        guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
    }
```

Comment: Your assignment `self.ref` in concurrent, asynchronous code is a concern. Other parts of your app can't rely on the value of `self.ref` if you modify it asynchronously. It is ok to store a reference to your base collection in a property, and set it once when your object is initialised but any other document or collection references should be in local variables. The same for other `self.` properties, such as your dispatch groups. These should also be local variables

Comment: @Paulw11 the thing is, I tried having them as local variables in the completion handler, but it still would not work.

Comment: Possibly, you may have another issue, but you definitely don't want to use all of those properties.  Show your code that invokes the delete. How do you update the UI after you delete the document? Do you re-fetch the data after the delete and then refresh the table view?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a ui bar button item in navigation, that if pressed, refreshes the table view by refetching the remaining data after deletion.

Comment: It appears you're deleting all the documents in a collection? If that's a lot of documents, it cold be a costly and time consuming operation. You may want to consider letting the server do it instead via a callable Cloud Function. See [Delete data with Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections). Your code may run into an asynch issue as the second .delete calls may occur before the first set of deletes complete. Lastly, are any replies returned in `getDocuments`?